# Getting all records starting from a specific record in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have an array of records from MongoDB like so :

```
[
{
id:'lkg59',
name:'Test 1'
},
{
id:'dkjnq7',
name:'Test 2'
},
{
id:'sd7x1',
name:'Test 3'
},
{
id:'4d5d7,
name:'Test 4'
},
{
id:'lkuca5',
name:'Test 5'
},
...
]
```

I want for example to get all the records that exists after `id:'sd7x1'` while `id:'sd7x1'` is included.
Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [**filter()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) you can check it out.

```js
const data = [{id:'lkg59',name:'Test 1'},{id:'dkjnq7',name:'Test 2'},{id:'sd7x1',name:'Test 3'},{id:'4d5d7',name:'Test 4'},{id:'lkuca5',name:'Test 5'}]

let isFound = false
const result = data.filter(i => {
    if (isFound) return isFound; 
    isFound = i.id === 'sd7x1'
    return isFound
})
console.log(result)
```

[**Array.prototype.find()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) might be more simpler. Using `find()` search the index of `sd7x1` and then [**slice**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) array from that index.

```js
const data = [{id:'lkg59',name:'Test 1'},{id:'dkjnq7',name:'Test 2'},{id:'sd7x1',name:'Test 3'},{id:'4d5d7',name:'Test 4'},{id:'lkuca5',name:'Test 5'}]

let result;
data.find((item, key) => item.id === 'sd7x1' && (!!(result = data.slice(key))));

console.log(result)
```

Comment: This could work if the id if always an `integer`, it was my fault, I have updated my questions, thank you

Comment: @RahmaniSeifelmoulouk updated the answer as per your requirements.

Comment: You are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`skip()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/index.html#set-the-starting-point-of-the-result-set) within your mongodb query like this:

```
db.<collection>.find().skip(2);
```

Where `<collection>` is your collection's name

Or you can use use [`Array.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

```js
const arr = [{id:'lkg59',name:'Test 1'},{id:'dkjnq7',name:'Test 2'},{id:'sd7x1',name:'Test 3'},{id:'4d5d7',name:'Test 4'},{id:'lkuca5',name:'Test 5'}];

console.log(
  arr.slice(2)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this with `forEach`

```js
const array = [{ id:'lkg59', name:'Test 1' },
{id:'dkjnq7', name:'Test 2' },
{ id:'sd7x1', name:'Test 3' },
{ id:'4d5d7', name:'Test 4' },
{ id:'lkuca5', name:'Test 5' }];

let valToStore = false;
let newArray = [];
array.forEach((v, i) => {
  if (v.id == "sd7x1") { valToStore = true; }
  if (valToStore) {
    newArray.push(v);
  }
});

console.log(newArray);
```